# 500 error for regular users, not for admin

Tags: admin, front-end, 500-internal-error

Not sure what's going on here.  Some of my pages (eg https://beatthatflight.com.au/) are getting 500 errors.  However other pages (https://beatthatflight.com.au/index.php/2022/12/19/56-fast-free-easy-ways-to-earn-qantas-frequent-flyer-points-in-december-2022/) are working fine.

I've disabled the theme, and all plugins, it made no difference. Cleared cache. Tried multiple browsers, but suspect it's not client side.

I've tried

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
```

in wp-config, but the debug.log and error.log files are empty.

I'm kinda stuck at this point.  I've reinstalled the latest wordpress, no difference.  I find it weird that a) some pages work and b) all pages work if I'm logged in as admin.

Update: https://beatthatflight.com.au/?nocache=1 works.  so caching...somewhere..seems to be an issue

Any recommendations appreciated.

Comment: At a guess I'd look into your host's caching system. The fact the site works when logged in (when cache isn't used) possibly points in that direction.

Comment: @vancoder might be on to something as https://beatthatflight.com.au/?nocache=1 works....hmmm

Comment: The `?nocache=1` points to the server cache. Did you install a caching plugin, or is that something handled by your hosting provider? If the former, check with the plugin's support team; if the latter, your hosting support.

Comment: @Pat I had caching plugins, but tried disabling all plugins and themes to no avail.  Still persists. So suspect server.  
We did find we had Nameservers going to ezoic which we no longer use, so I've just updated those and hoping that might resolve things